# Created New User - User Exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I went to create a `user=User.new (:screen_name => "jeff holmes", :email "jeff92@jeff.com", :password "1234")` I had some validations I was trying to see if it would pass:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_uniqueness_of :screen_name, :email
  validates_length_of :screen_name, :within => 4...20
  validates_length_of :password, :within => 4...20
  validates_length_of :email, :within => 6...50

  def validate
    errors.add(:email, 'must be valid.') unless email.include? ("@")
    errors.add(:screen_name, 'cannot include spaces.') if screen_name.include?(" ")
  end
end
```

After I try to create the user all this stuff pops up and I have no idea what it is.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
        from (irb):3
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/RubymineProjects/worklink/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Then after all that stuff pops up I go `user.save` and this appears.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
```

Whats going on? What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: i didn't get your problem ..

Comment: without validations ther won't even be a problem. we can only guess, and i follow Arup Rakshit - "i didn't get your problem..."

Comment: I have validations but maybe they are not working?

Comment: you need to show us your validations.

Comment: *Then after that stuff pops up I go `user.save`*... I don't know what this means. What do you mean, "I go"? Did you type it in at a console? What's the context? If the error is that `user` is undefined, then it means just that: it's a name that isn't assigned anything in the context it was used in.

Comment: Sorry, yes I typed user.save int he rails console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% certain on the problem at hand but here's a little overview of the create process

```
user = User.new # creates the user object/instance but DOES NOT save or populate the ID column/attribute/method
# OR ... 
user = User.new(params[:user]) # often what you see in a controller action
user.valid? # checks to ensure your validations pass ... duh :) 
user.save # saves the users
# from here, you can do a few things: 
user.persisted? # this checks if the user was saved in the DB
user.id 
# will now show you the user's id ... 
# in your original post's code it appears you check for the id _before_ the save and it has to be saved before that attribute/method is populated.
```

The `User Exists` is Rails checking to see if that user is already in the DB before it tries to save it (my sense is that your User model validates the `email` and `screen_name` methods/attributes)

As for seeing the user after it's created you can do a couple of things:

1. If you're in a console, just type `user` to get the output.
2. In a web view (read: browser), you would go to http://localhost:3000/users/ID_OF_NEW_USER (this assumes you have a show action in your UsersController and a show view (show.html.erb or show.html.haml) ... and if you generated a scaffold (`rails generate scaffold User email:string ...`, you have these!)

Again, not totally sure I understood your request but I hope this helps you understand this flow a little better.

UPDATE: 
Just saw the additions to your post. This code is incorrect:

```
user=User.new (:screen_name => "jeff holmes", :email "jeff92@jeff.com", :password "1234")
```

It should be

```
user=User.new (:screen_name => "jeff_holmes", :email => "jeff92@jeff.com", :password => "1234") # note the missing '=>' for email and password and the space in the screen_name, which is invalid according to the model
```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I see these users I have created?

Comment: No problem! In a browser, you could go to `http://localhost:3000/users` and that would display the `index` action of the UsersController, which (typically) lists out all users in the system. Again, that assumes you either created that action or scaffolded your User model, etc. In a console, you can just do users = User.all and check out the full list of users in your DB!

Comment: When is type `user = User.all` I get this:


`irb(main):001:0> users = User.all
/Users/coreyholmes/RubymineProjects/worklink/app/models/user.rb:22: warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/
ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?`

Comment: It's probably a wonky regexp in your validation expression ... can you post user.rb line 22? Just want to see it before I respond!

Comment: User.rb Line 22     :with => /^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,

Comment: Try this: `/\A[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\z/` ... that might be slightly off but it's the \A and \z that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine.

```
user = User.create name: "name", email: "email@test.com", password: "123456"
```

By calling the create method of a class its running all validations. Unless they failed its calling the save method. Since user is a new_object? rails will create the user.

After that you are having the user instance in your variable "user".

The other way is

```
user = User.new
user.email = "test@test.de"
....
user.save
```

Here again, the save method will call validations, and if they pass it will save the object to the database.

You can get the ID with user.id or User.last (which will load the latest user out of the database).

The best way to test those behaviors and play with it is the rails console. you can run it with **rails c**

you are doing fine.

just a little hint: have a look at the gem called "devise" which implements you a complete user-auth logic within 15 minues. no line of code needs to be written.